# Show that natural numbers can be put in one-to-one correspondence with proper subset

Tags: real-analysis

How can we show that the natural numbers can be put in one-to-one correspondence with a proper subset? Can I just say they have the same cardinality?

Comment: That's what you have to show.

Comment: The definition of the relation between sets of *having the same cardinality* is exactly : there exists a bijection (or one-to-one correspondence) between the two sets.

Answer (score 3):

$f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N, n\mapsto n+1$ is a bijection between the natural numbers and one of its proper subsets.